# Java show OAuth webpage

Tags: java, oauth, webview, html

I am developing a Java desktop application and need to access the LinkedIn API. In order to do this, the user has to login on the webpage that LinkedIn sends me back. But how can I easily integrate that in my application?

JEditorPane is not meant to show html pages and it really does not look good at all, so that is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have You seen Scribe? It has LinkedIn support out of the box, looks like you may be able to use it...

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/LinkedInExample.java

Comment: The OAuth is not the problem here. The problem is to render the webpage where the user can login. I use scribe to access the LinkedIn API and it gives me a webpage back (https://...) where the user should authorize himself so that my application is authorized.

But how can I render the webpage in Java swing? The JEditorPane is just ugly because it does not support css decently.

Comment: Ah, I see... Maybe you're going about this the wrong way. Why not have the user enter their login info in a Java Dialog Box, and the program logs them in in the background...